# Anypoint Studio - Flow reference - How to find referenced flow?

Tags: ide, mule, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

In Anypoint Studio you can add flow references, so you could re-use and decompose your flows.

Using this approach you end up quickly with many refences and it would be nice to quickly navigate between them.

Is it possible to quickly jump to the referenced flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the referenced flow by selecting the flow-reference in the flow-editor and pressing F3.

This is a shortcut for the "Go to referenced flow" option from the context menu:

[image: "Go to referenced flow" in the context menu.]

This context menu can be opened by right clicking on the flow-reference.

Please note - you can also use the F3 shortcut on API-Kit-Routers. In this case the option is not available in the context menu, but you can still use it using the F3 shortcut.

In this case you get a list of all the possible routes:

[image: "Go to referenced flow" - API-Kit Router]